# SVG or HTML text that scales to fully fit a container so it stretches, bot vertically and horizontally, disregarding aspect ratio

Tags: svg, text

I need to make text automatically stretch in both dimensions, to fill a container. It will distort.

This shows the the container space in red
[image: Plate1.jpg]

This shows what a long name would normally resize to put in that space and maintaining aspect ratio
[image: Plate2.jpg].

This shows what my client wants to happen
[image: Plate3.jpg].

I would prefer to use SVG but I will work with what works.

I have searched for a solution to the best of my abilities but all seem to either refer to maintaining aspect ratio or stretching text when the page or viewbox changes dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text is already part of an SVG (as it appears in your example), you will probably need to use a nested `<svg>` element.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">

  <rect width="400" height="400" fill="rebeccapurple"/>
  
  <!-- rect representing area that our text has to squeeze into -->
  <rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="50" fill="white"/>

  <!-- x y width height match above rect -->
  <!-- viewBox values need to match text bounds -->
  <svg x="20" y="50" width="200" height="50"
       viewBox="0 8 244 28" preserveAspectRatio="none">

    <text x="0" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35">
      HELLO THERE
    </text>
  </svg>  
    
</svg>
```

The hardest part is workoing out the correct values for `viewBox`. It needs to match the bounds of the (normal unsqueezed) text.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a broad question, but yes you can do it with svg, I'll let you implement it though since you didn't provided anything to chew on.

The key point is to set your svg's [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) to `"none"`:

```css
svg{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  }
body{
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 300 40" preserveAspectRatio="none">

  <text x="0" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35">
    Hello, out there
  </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't know where to start.  Nothing has worked. So svg{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  } will give the result along with preserveAspectRatio="none"?

Comment: @SteveSnider You are welcome, you may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers